# Unexpected caching behaviour for groupBy/join operations in spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have been trying to do multiple aggregations on a base data frame lets say df1.
When I run the following code

```
df1.cache()
val df2 = df1.groupBy(col("col1"),col("col2") as "col6").agg(sum("col3"))
val df3 = df1.groupBy(col("col1"),col("col4") as "col6").agg(sum("col5"))
val df4 = df2.join(df3,Seq("col1","col6"),"outer")
df4.count()
```

In the query plan generated and on the SQL tab of the spark UI. I see that df2 is an in memory table scan of df1 while the complete DAG of d1 is executed for df3 generation.

When I rename the column1 while doing the join

```
df1.cache()
val df2 = df1.groupBy(col("col1") as "col1",col("col2") as "col6").agg(sum("col3"))
val df3 = df1.groupBy(col("col1") as "col1",col("col4") as "col6").agg(sum("col5"))
val df4 = df2.join(df3,Seq("col1","col6"),"outer")
df4.count()
```

Both the DFs are In memory table scans.

I didn't think this would make a difference, can someone please explain me why this could be happening.

PS: Also one more thing that i noticed is that without the join queryPlans of both the df's are inMemory table scan.

Comment: There used to be a bug in Spark where if you joined two datasets which had the same ultimate parent in the DAG, it would screw up the join and do a cross join. This *could* be an artefact of the fix for that? However this is also certainly a bug.